# In Java, is there a simple way to generate random N bits, but make sure that there is at least ONE bit equals 1 for all N bits?

Tags: java, random

As for N, it could be as large as 179.

For example, I was able to do it for n up to 32 bits:

```
new Random().nextInt(2^n-1)+1
```

nextLong() is not possible because I can't pass a value to it and it only generates a random value up to 48-bit.

Comment: Shift a 1 a random number of bits up to size in the randomly generated bit string

Comment: For any non-zero number, you are guaranteed a non-zero bit. Any random non-zero number is a sequence of random bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use BigInteger to create a random number. If it happens to be zero, try again.

```
public static BigInteger randomForBitsNonZero(int numBits, Random r) {
    BigInteger candidate = new BigInteger(numBits, r);
    while(candidate.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        candidate = new BigInteger(numBits, r); 
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

This will be randomly distrubted about the number of bits. It is very unlikely that the if statement will ever trigger for a significantly high `numBits` but the protection is good for compelteness and because you might have low `numBits` sometimes that would roll a 0 very often.

Comment: I would use a `do ... while` loop for this.  That way, you only need one `candidate = new BigInteger(numBits, r);` statement rather than two.

Comment: You might, but they're so *rarely* used that they take away from readability. If I was going to do that, I'd just do `while(true) { BigI can = new BigI(...); if (can.equals(BigI.ZERO)) return can; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random.nextBytes()` to generate as many random bytes as you want.  The number of bytes you need is (number-of-bits + 1) / 8.

Then in order to ensure that at least one bit is set to 1, you can pick a bit, any bit, at random, and set it to 1, follows:

```
 int bitIndex = random.nextInt( N );
 int byteIndex = bitIndex / 8;
 bitIndex = bitIndex % 8;
 randomBytes[byteIndex] |= (1 << bitIndex);
```

Comment: The "set a random bit" introduces a bias into the PRNG.  Better to test if the "number" (i.e. all bytes in your example) is zero and try again.

Comment: @StephenC true.